# Combining tbf with other qdiscs?

Tags: linux, tc

It looks like a subset of classless qdiscs can be combined with each other in certain configurations.  In fact it doesn't make sense to me that you could *not* do this, since things like codel will only work sanely if you can limit the outgoing bandwidths using another mechanism (eg a token bucket).

I cannot, however, find any sane documentation. Are there any good examples or writeups about combining classless qdiscs to achieve target rate-limiting and fairness behavior?